# How to add an auto-incremental number at the end of a result?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to add a number that auto increments at the end of a select result?
for example, if I have a table called people with a field "name" and I want to select all the names and add a "_x" at the end (x being a number that increases)

| name |
| --- |
| Richard |
| John |
| Peter |
| Bob |

Is there a way to make a
`select concat(name, number_that_increments) from people`and get as result: Richard_1, John_2, Peter_3, Bob_4, etc..?

Comment: [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-row_number/) is a window function that can be used to identity the _row number_ in your result set.

Comment: Thank you @AnthonyForloney, that was just the function I needed

Answer (score 0):

Use the function `ROW_NUMBER` to enumerate your rows, e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE t (name text);
INSERT INTO t VALUES
('Richard'),('John'),('Peter'),('Bob');

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (),name FROM t;

 row_number |  name   
------------+---------
          1 | Richard
          2 | John
          3 | Peter
          4 | Bob
(4 rows)
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=139d074b538e3f0f0e0071fc835e7b4e)

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
select concat(name, '_', row) 
from (select row_number() over () as row,* from people) as people_row;
```

and this is results:

**Richard_1**

**John_2**

**Peter_3**

**Bob_4**

Answer (score 0):

The function you want is `row_number()`.  In the context of your query:

```
select name || row_number() over () 
from people
```

Note:

- `||` is the *standard* and Postgres-supported string concatenation operator.
- `over ()` provides the enumeration in an *arbitrary* fashion.  If you expect a particular ordering, then use `order by <some column or expression>`.
- The numbers are of different length, so you will get `'X-1'`, `'X-10'`, `'X-100'`, and so on.
- If you wanted a separate enumeration (starting at `1`) then use `partition by name` in the windows clause.